# I have a problem to extract images from video and save them to specific folder

Tags: python, image, video, directory, frame

everyone.
I'm a struggling freshman for programming.
I'll really appreciate any of your help or advice.

I want to make this code do these jobs.

1. Read video files in specific folder.
2. Extract frame image from this video file
3. Save them in specific folder(ex. from video_1.mp4, make folder video_1_frameimage and save images video_1_frame0, video_1_frame300, ..... and so on into this specific folder)

To make this function I made this code but it doesn't work that nicely.

Thank you for reading my question!

```
    import cv2
    import os
    
    path_for_video = "C:/Users/정지원/Desktop/Video_files"
    video_list = os.listdir(path_for_video)
    
    for video_file in video_list:
        file_path= os.path.join(path_for_video,video_file)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
        index = 0
        while (True):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == False:
                break
            if index % 300 == 0:
                name = video_file + '_frame' + str(index) + '.jpg'
                print('Creating...' + name)
                if not os.path.exists('C:/Users/정지원/Desktop/Video_files/'+ video_file):
                    os.makedirs('C:/Users/정지원/Desktop/Video_files/' + video_file)
                path_for_image = 'C:/Users/정지원/Desktop/Video_files/' + video_file

                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_for_image, name), frame)

            index += 1
    
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain more about your problem: "it doesn't work that nicely" doesn't tell us anything. What does it actually do? Is there an error? Imagine going to a doctor and just saying "something is wrong, fix it". (One error I see is `cap.release` should be called inside the loop, where you create it)

Comment: Hi Amadan. When I run this code in pycharm, it runs without error, But I can't find any result from this program(ex new folder, framed image file...etc). So I'm confusing why this thing happened.

Comment: Either use a debugger, or put in some `print` statements. I would check `video_list`, `video_file`, `ret`, `index` and `os.path.join(path_for_image, name)` at appropriate points to see what exactly the code _is_ doing (as opposed to what I think it _should_ be doing).

Comment: I can check
'video_list = os.listdir(path_for_video)' 
is working when I insert print(video_list).
Also I can see 'Creating~' part also do its job.

Still I can't find any result from this program in anywhere in my compyter.

Comment: I don't work with Windows much, but one possibility I can think of is that hanja might be tripping it up. Python typically works with Unicode, Windows file system might not be. Can you check if there is a weird new folder in `C:\Users`?

Comment: I can't find any weird folder in that directory. Will it be helpful to change my computer name in english?

Comment: I don't know (and also, even if you change your name, your folder name would likely not be changed, from my slight experience). Actually never mind — you're successfully listing the directory, so you should be able to write to the same place too. You reported which prints happen partially; does `imwrite` happen? Does the frame loop execute multiple times (i.e. does `index` get past `0`?

Comment: It seems like imwrite doesn't function. But loop is function. I can see Creating ~~~ frame0.jpg ... frame300.jpg and so on.

Comment: `cv2.imwrite` apparently doesn't like exceptions, and instead returns a boolean value to signify whether a write was successful or not. It may be the case Python doesn't have permission to write there. Try to write something else there (e.g. `open('C:/Users/정지원/Desktop/Video_files/test.txt', 'wt').write('test')`, and see if it works. (yes, in proper code use `with`, but this this is fine for a tiny quick and dirty test.)

Comment: I can see test.txt file in "C:/Users/정지원/Desktop/Video_files" directory.

Comment: How about the `imwrite` return value? Can you also try to change the `jpg` to `bmp`?

Comment: I still can't get return value from ' imwrite' .

Comment: What do you mean, you can't get return value? All Python functions return a value, even if it is `None`. `result = cv2.imwrite(...); print(result)` should say something on the console.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I got confused. According to your code, it shows
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - imwrite() missing required argument 'img' (pos 2)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean literal `...`, I just didn't want to type what you wrote. It should be this: `result = cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_for_image, name), frame)` followed by `print(result)`. Also, you never answered about trying `bmp` instead of `jpg`.

Comment: It says 'FALSE'. I tried 'bmp', but nothing changed.

Comment: Besides I don't know why all my comments can't change code into gray background one. If you don't mind can you tell me how to do it? I thought it might be 'code' but seems not function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. OpenCV is saying it couldn't save the file, but describes no reason, so it's a bit of a nightmare to debug. (As for StackOverflow code markup, [use backticks as quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).)

Comment: How can I give you a reputation? I'd love to do that.

Comment: You can't, unless I provide an answer. Unfortunately, I could not provide an answer. (Also, don't worry, I will not starve for reputation :P )